# How to get a count of all the files in a git repository?

Tags: git

How would you get a count of all the files currently in a git repository?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can get a count of all tracked files in a git respository by using the following command:

```
git ls-files | wc -l
```

Command Breakdown:

- The `git ls-files` command by itself prints out a list of all the tracked files in the repository, one per line.
- The `|` operator funnels the output from the preceding command into the command following the pipe.
- The `wc -l` command calls the [word count (wc) program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29). Passing the `-l` flag asks it to return the total number of lines.

**Note:** This returns a count of only the *tracked* files in the repository meaning that any ignored files or new & uncommitted files will not be counted.

Comment: And if you want to count ony for certain file extensions it's easy to pipe through grep like `git ls-files | grep "\.js$" | wc -l` for JavaScript (.js) files

Comment: In case 1000 files were commited and pushed and then all of them deleted and pushed again, will git ls-files still show those 1000 files? Is there a way to show all the tracked references and also is there a way to show only those files, that are present in the current commit?

Comment: [this won't work if a file has `'\n'` in its name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). You need `git ls-files -z | grep -zc "^"`

Comment: An alternative to using grep to get the count for a file extension as suggested by mnorrish is `git ls-files -x *.js -i | wc -l` the `-x` tells the files to exclude and `-i` tells to only include the excluded files. This works on windows and is less characters to type :)

Comment: This counts the files in the current branch, is there also some way to count all the files in all branches?

Comment: As of July 2020, using git version 2.26.2.windows.1, neither `git ls-files` or `git ls-files -z` works for me under the bash v4.4 shell on WIndows 10.

Comment: is there a way to count the files under a subfolder of a repo to ?

Answer (score 7):

Just to build on the accepted answer, you can also filter which types of files you want to count.

**Count only `.json` files**

```sh
# Will output only json file paths
git ls-files "./*.json" | wc -l
```

**Count only `.c` files**

```sh
git ls-files "./*.c" | wc -l
```

A fairly useful way to gauge what languages are common in a repo...

Answer (score 6):

If you came here looking for a way to do this for a repo hosted on github without cloning it, you can do this:

```
svn ls -R https://github.com/exampleproject/branches/master | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for Windows using PowerShell

```
git ls-files | %{ Get-Content -Path $_ } | measure
```

Comment: This answer did not work but this one worked for me: `(git ls-files | Measure-Object -line).Lines`

Answer (score 3):

In the github repository view there is no way, you can clone or download the project and use an external tool.

If you are comfortable with command-line tools, you can install `git-sizer` and run it against a repository you have cloned locally.  It can tell you more about your repository than you ever wanted to know.

Check out [tokei](https://github.com/Aaronepower/tokei) and [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer).