# How to count number of tracked files in each sub-directory of the repository?

Tags: git, git-bash

In a git repo, I want to list directories (and sub-directories) that contain tracked items and the number items (tracked **files** only) in each of them.

[The following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247815/2093077) gives list of directories:

`$ git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq`

, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468981/2093077) counts all tracked items in the repository:

`$ git ls-files | wc -l`

[The following command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23134) counts files in all sub-directories:

`$ find . -type d -exec sh -c "echo '{}'; ls -1 '{}' | wc -l" \; | xargs -n 2 | awk '{print $1" "$2}'`

But it also counts the directories themselves and, of course, it does not care if files are tracked. Take a look at the example below for more explanation:

```
C:\ROOT
│   tracked1.txt
│
├───Dir1
│   ├───Dir11
│   │       tracked111.txt
│   │       tracked112.txt
│   │
│   └───Dir12
│           ignored121.tmp
│           tracked121.txt
│
└───Dir2
    │   ignored21.tmp
    │   Tracked21.txt
    │
    └───Dir21
            ignored211.tmp
            ignored212.tmp
```

Running `$ find root -type d -exec sh -c "echo '{}'; ls -1 '{}' | wc -l" \; | xargs -n 2 | awk '{print $2", "$1}'` command gives the following result:

> 3, root
> 2, root/Dir1
> 2, root/Dir1/Dir11
> 2, root/Dir1/Dir12
> 3, root/Dir2
> 2, root/Dir2/Dir21

What I need is:

> <del>3</del> **1**, root
> <s>2, root/Dir1</s>
> 2, root/Dir1/Dir11
> <s>2</s> **1**, root/Dir1/Dir12
> <s>3</s>  **1**, root/Dir2
> <s>2, root/Dir2/Dir21</s>

, where sub-directories and ignored items are not counted, and directories with no tracked items are not included. But I don't know how to pipe these commands to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git ls-files | awk '{$NF="";print}' FS=/ OFS=/ | sort | uniq -c
```

or, shorter,

```
git ls-files | sed 's,[^/]*$,,' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code lists all files, groups them by their directory names and prints the size of each group:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | awk ' { filescount[$1] += 1 }
     END { 
         n=asorti(filescount, sortedpath); 
         for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print filescount[sortedpath[i]], sortedpath[i] 
         }'
```

```
1 .
1 Root
2 Root/Dir1/Dir11
1 Root/Dir1/Dir12
1 Root/Dir2
```

If you also need the total number of lines of code in each directory:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs -n1 wc -l | awk ' { sub("/[^/]*$", "/") } 1' | 
awk ' { filescount[$2] += 1; linescount[$2] += $1 }
     END { 
         n=asorti(filescount, sortedpath); 
         for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
            print filescount[sortedpath[i]], linescount[sortedpath[i]], sortedpath[i] 
         }'
```

```
1 260 .gitignore
1 5 Root/
2 1 Root/Dir1/Dir11/
1 2 Root/Dir1/Dir12/
1 4 Root/Dir2/
```

The second command does not group files of the root directory and adds a separate line for each of them. The problem is in `awk ' { sub("/[^/]*$", "/") } 1'` part that tries to extract directories from a path. It fails and returns the whole path when there is no parent directory in the path (e.g. `.gitignore`).